# Listar directorios por tamaño c++

Tags: c++

Hice un codigo para buscar los nombres de los directorios y ponerlos en un archivo de texto.

```
void buscar_directorio(string dir) {    
    if (directorio = opendir(dir.c_str())) {
        file.open("Ruta.txt.");
        if (file.good()) {
                while (elemento = readdir(directorio)) {
                elem = elemento->d_name;
                file << elem;
                cout << elem << endl;
                file << endl;
            }
            file.close();
        }
        else { cout << "Imposible guardar la ruta..." << endl; }
    }
    closedir(directorio);
}
```

Mi pregunta es si existe alguna forma de guardar el tamaño de estos archivos que se encuentran en un directorio especifico o debo ingresarlos manualmente.

Comment: Puedes empezar por mirar la función [`stat( )`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html).

Answer (score 1):

Puedes acumular en una variable los tamaños de los archivos de un directorio. Puedes pedir su tamaño con [`filesystem::file_size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_size):

```
auto tamanyo_directorio(const std::filesystem::path &ruta)
{
    std::uintmax_t result{};

    for (const auto &archivo: std::filesystem::directory_iterator(ruta))
        result += std::filesystem::file_size(archivo);

    return result;
}
```